# Play a video from cache using AVPlayer in Swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, video, swift3, avfoundation, avplayer

I am creating a video based application in Swift3. When I am trying to play any video from video url then video is playing perfectly using AVPlayer.

But, The problem is it's taking more time to play when there will be multiple videos. So, I have downloaded my videos to cache memory. After passing file path of video in AVPlayer, my Video is not playing.

Here is my code to play video from file path:

```
 let filePath = "file://var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/00E55D26-18D1-49CC-BB72-F3225A03C289/Library/Caches/90.mp4"

 var url = NSURL(string: filePath)

 let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url:NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath) as URL)
 playerItem.videoComposition = videoComposition
 self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
```

Can anyone please suggest me, where is my mistake? This FilePath is not correct?

Comment: what `url` returns

Comment: file://var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/00E55D26-18D1-49CC-BB72-F3225A03C289/Library/Caches/90.mp4

Comment: I believe application ID 00E55D26-18D1-49CC-BB72-F3225A03C289 changes from installation to installation so obviously absolute file path to data saved in cache will not work.

Comment: But my url is also not working in browser

Comment: use finder -> go to folder -> paste the url and check if mp4 actually exists and try playing from there

Comment: If your intention is to cache the data while you play the audio/video you can make use AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate. Though there are open source code in Github mostly in objective-C I guess I ended up writing my own thats pretty easy

Answer (score 0):

You already have the full `fileURLWithPath` string in the variable `filePath`. You just need to instead put `let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url:NSURL(string: filePath) as URL)`